# FFMPEG - fade in logo watermark independent of fade in video and subtitles

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I'm on a windows 7 box using FFmpeg version: 20170223-dcd3418 and would like to control the fade in timing of my logo watermark independent of the fade already built in to my video.

This code is working OK but I can't work out how to fade the watermark without also fading my input video stream.

```
ffmpeg -y -i mainvideo.mp4 -i watermarklogo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10, fade=in:0:20[tmp_overlay]; [tmp_overlay]subtitles=ep1.srt[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

I've tried a number of combinations but am out of my depth with FFMPEG's -filter_complex command so any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i mainvideo.mp4 -loop 1 -t 2 -i watermarklogo.png 
  -filter_complex
        "[1]fade=0:1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS+N/TB[wm];
         [0:v][wm]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10,fade=in:0:20,subtitles=ep1.srt[out]"
  -map [out] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -c:a aac output.mp4
```

The `0:1` sets a 1 second fade-in.

The `N` in `PTS+N/TB` sets the start time of the fade-in in seconds.

Ordinarily, one should be able to skip the `-t 2` and just use `shortest=1` in the overlay filter. But, at the time of writing, there's a bug with the shortest filter, so this workaround is needed. Just make sure the `t` value is greater than the fade duration.